# Create PagedList with non database properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel, pagedlist

With the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Name(s)")]
    public string MiddleNames { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> name = new List<string>();
            name.Add(this.FirstName);
            name.Add(this.MiddleNames);
            name.Add(this.Surname);
            return String.Join(" ", name.Where(n => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n)));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create a [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) of a view model like below:

```
public class PersonSearch
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I can't use the below as it gives me an error on Name which is as expected

```
var model = db.person.OrderBy(p => p.Surname)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
                    .Select(p => new PersonSearch
                    {
                        PersonId = p.PersonId,
                        Name = p.Name
                    })
                    .ToPagedList(page, 25);
```

> The specified type member 'Name' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

The following works but it brings across the entire list of people first:

```
var model = db.person.OrderBy(p => p.Surname)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(p => new PersonSearch
                    {
                        PersonId = p.PersonId,
                        Name = p.Name
                    })
                    .ToPagedList(page, 25);
```

And the following doesn't work as it removes the paging information:

```
var model = db.person.OrderBy(p => p.Surname)
                    .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
                    .ToPagedList(page, 25);
                    .Select(p => new PersonSearch
                    {
                        PersonId = p.PersonId,
                        Name = p.Name
                    })
                    .ToPagedList(page, 25);
```

Comment: What do you want `Name` to be? - `Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName`?

Comment: I want it to be `FirstName + " " + MiddleNames + " " + LastName` when these data items are present. Some of these data items are NULL in the data I am querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `PersonSearch` model so that you can generate the full name

```
public class PersonSearch
{
  public PersonSearch()
  {
  }
  public PersonSearch(string first, string middle, string last)
  {
    // format and remove leading or trailing white space as a result of nulls
    string name = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", first, middle, last).Trim();
    // remove any internal extra white space if middle is null
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middle))
    {
      name = String.Join(" ", name.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
    Name = name;
  }
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your query use

```
var model = db.person.OrderBy(p => p.Surname).ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
  .Select(p => new PersonSearch(p.FirstName, p.MiddleNames, p.Surname)
  {
    PersonId = p.PersonId
  }).ToPagedList(page, 25);
```